# Inline RowMapper<T> calling JdbcTemplate.query(String!, RowMapper<T!>!, vararg Any!)

Tags: kotlin, spring-jdbc

I can't get the `vararg` to work with `JdbcTemplate.query(String!, RowMapper<T!>!, vararg Any!)`.  If I leave the variable arguments off, it seems to work.  For example:

This works:

```
fun translates(field: String) = template.query("SELECT key, value FROM table", {
    rs: ResultSet, _: Int -> Pair(rs.getString("key"), rs.getString("value"))
})
```

or this works:

```
fun translates(field: String) = template.query("SELECT key, value FROM table") {
    rs: ResultSet, _: Int -> Pair(rs.getString("key"), rs.getString("value"))
}
```

But this ***doesn't*** work (I've added `, field` at the end of the function call which should match the function `query(String!, RowMapper<T!>!, vararg Any!)`):

```
fun translates(field: String) = template.query("SELECT key, value FROM table WHERE field = ?", {
    rs: ResultSet, _: Int -> Pair(rs.getString("key"), rs.getString("value"))
}, field)
```

This is the relevant part of the error message:

```
query(String!, RowMapper<T!>!, vararg Any!)
  where T cannot be inferred for
  fun <T : Any!> query(sql: String!, rowMapper: RowMapper<T!>!, vararg args: Any!): (Mutable)List<T!>!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may help the compiler to infer the type of the lambda in the middle, by saying `RowMapper { .. }`:

```
fun translates(field: String) = template.query("SELECT key, value FROM table", RowMapper { rs: ResultSet, _: Int ->
    Pair(rs.getString("key"), rs.getString("value"))
  }, field)
```

Adding the `RowMapper` made Kotlin SAM work
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html

Comment: Thanks, I knew it would be something like that but I couldn't find any examples of people using JdbcTemplate (and I didn't know what to search for the general syntax...)